# How do I take the User Profile Store Offline

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, unit-testing

For testing purposes I need to take SharePoint's User Profile service offline, imitating the user profile store not having started after a reboot. Stopping the User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service seem to not have had an effect as I can still query against UP metadata and have it returned. Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Comment: Stop the service on all the servers that runs it from central admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, reset the box. Running `iisreset` resolved it